# Adding new field to create account form in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I have a problem with adding new field in customer create account form. Field shows properly in admin panel add new customer form, but not in frontend create account. I created module like this:

MyModules\CustomerMarketingFields\Setup\InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace MyModules\CustomerMarketingFields\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "regulation",  array(
        "type"     => "int",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Regulation",
        "input"    => "boolean",
        "source"   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

    ));

    $regulation   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "regulation");

    $regulation = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'regulation');
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
    $regulation->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);
    $regulation->save();

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

MyModules\CustomerMarketingFields\View\Frontend\layout\customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my_form_additional_info_customer" template="MyModules_CustomerMarketingFields::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

MyModules\CustomerMarketingFields\View\Frontend\templates\additionalinfocustomer.phtml

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>

<p>
<div class="field regulation required">
    <label for="regulation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Regulation') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="checkbox" checked name="regulation" id="regulation" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Regulation') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
    </div>
</div>
</p>
</fieldset>
```

Files module.xml and registration.php are not included here. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You will find you answer here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95511/add-field-to-customer-registation-form-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working for me

MyModules/CustomerMarketingFields/etc/modules.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Samumaretiya. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="MyModules_CustomerMarketingFields" setup_version="2.0.0">
  <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
 </module>
</config>
```

Layout

MyModules/CustomerMarketingFields/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```html
Layout

MyModules/CustomerMarketingFields/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="MyModules_CustomerMarketingFields::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

templates

MyModules/CustomerMarketingFields/view/frontend/templates/additionalinfocustomer.phtml

```html
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>

<p>
<div class="field regulation required">
    <label for="regulation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Regulation') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="checkbox" checked name="regulation" id="regulation" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Regulation') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
    </div>
</div>
</p>
</fieldset>
```

The above code is working for me. could you please make view, layout ,frontend etc in lowercase

after doing above please fire the following command from cmd

sudo php "Your magento 2 installation folder name"/bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo chmod -R 777 "Your magento 2 installation folder name"

Let me know if you have any query or doubts

Comment: i created filed in additional info but . on registration page , additional info block is not visible only. how to enable that block????